# Fancy box работает не корректно на всех мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, fancybox

Есть сайт, который работает на joomla. Для отображения товара и просмотра фото используется fancy box. Он работает полностью корректно и нормально на компьютере, но на мобильных устройствах есть проблема.

При просмотре фото, при нажатии на смену фото ничего не происходит. Ничего не меняется и браузер не реагирует. Ну понять как это исправить, так как дебаггер пуст и не отображает никаких js ошибок.

Здесь можно увидеть это - [ссылка](http://www.luxselle.com/clothing). Извините за ссылку, но так нагляднее видно проблему. Как можно это исправить или хотя бы определить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш fancybox и на компьютере не супер работает, имеются JS запросы которые тормозят смену картинки , так же и в мобильной версии, есть картинки которые сразу открываются, но и есть которые открываются не каждый раз. Думаю проблема кроется именно в вертикальном слайдере `lSSlideOuter` который по какой то причине инициализируется больше 20 раз!(см скрин) + выдаёт конфликты иногда. Попробуйте поменять данный слайдер на более новую версию (если конечно вы сами что то не меняли в данном слайдере).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]